# How do I uninstall applications from my applications window

Tags: uninstall

I want to uninstall every application that is shown in this image.  I get to this point by clicking on "Show Applications" from the dock in Ubuntu 18.

[image]

Many of these applications have weird names or were installed in packages so I do not know what their exact name is.

I can't believe they do not have an uninstall option when I right click on them.

I am interested in how I could uninstall *any* application installed on my computer that shows up in applications, not just the ones pictured.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/alsa-tools-gui has them.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/alsa-tools-gui shows they are in universe; so there's a good chance you installed them (as not on original iso).  You'll have to check if you need them, if not `sudo apt remove alsa-tools-gui` will remove them all (plus other gui based tools for specific hardware)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installations that you installed using the Software Center or using "apt" or "apt-get" from the command line can be seamlessly removed again using these tools. If you installed software in other ways, i.e. by downloading an installation program from the internet, or compiling yourself, then you are responsible yourself for checking how the program is installed and how you eventually can remove it. There is no general advice possible here on how to remove such software, and you need to check the documentation of the program if any is available.

If removal proves to be difficult, you still could get rid of the application icon in the dock. That way, you do not remove the software itself with a risk of breaking your system if it is software not from the repositories, but at least you are not anymore bothered by the icons.

To that aim, locate the launcher files for these applications. These launchers will usually reside in /usr/share/applications, but may also be in the hidden folder .local/share/applications.

Now copy .desktop files you want to hide from /usr/share/applications to .local/share/applications. With a text editor, edit the .desktop files so that they include a line

```
NoDisplay=true
```

This way, these icons will not anymore show up in the menu for your user. The change takes effect immediately.

To have the icons not show up for any user, you will need administrator rights. Either you can edit the .desktop files in /usr/share/applications in a similar way as root, or merely delete the .desktop files in order for them to disappear from the application menu for all users.